# Collecting data in multiple activities and to display those values in final activity for preview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Can any one please help me ..!!  I want to collect some details in 3 forms i.e,(activity) and at final i need to display the data collected, for preview. Eg: In first activity I am entering the Personal details, then in  the second activity entering the Address Details and in third activity entering the qualification details. After the third activity I want to display the data entered in  all the three activity in a fourth activity for the preview purpose .. I have searched for the solution only for passing data between only 2 activities .. i need that for multiple activities.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// on the first activity when you are fill all the data then 
//And just about to go on second activity through intent then pass all the values like this and get it on second  and so on...


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayActivity.class);

    //Create a bundle object

    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    //Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle

    b.putString("name", name.getText().toString());


    //Add the bundle to the intent.

    intent.putExtras(b);

    //start the DisplayActivity

    startActivity(intent);



    //On the second activity get the first 
    Value of form data

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    b.getCharSequence("name");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply .. the core thing is I want to display the data entered in the first , second , third activity to the fourth activity . or I have to fetch the first , second , third activity input values and to display in the fourth activity .. without using the sqlite database

Comment: So whats the problem..?when you are on second activity then again pass these value on third Activity..     or either make a class and implements with paracelable interface and paas object instead of values..

Comment: Follow this link, so that u can understand how can we pass object through one activity to another one..  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/

Comment: Hi shahid I got the solution as you said.. but when the input value is more than 20 in single activity , So I want to fetch the input values directly to the preview page without using intent .. This application is kind of form enrollment .. So if there is any solution please do update thank you .

Comment: @Sri Krishna,if you have more than 20 inputs in a single page then you could make a pojo class and that pojo class should be implements with parcelable interface...and you have to paas only that object from one activity to another one...      here exapmle is given if u are not aware of parcelable interface http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/              .hope it will be helped you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have some POJO called Preview and you have three other Java Class to store values from each Activity;

```
public class Preview implements Serializable{

    private Activity1Data data1;
    private Activity2Data data2;
    private Activity3Data data3;

   //create getter and setter for all 
   //.........
}
```

Then on each Activity, you will set their value to corresponding field on instance of Preview i.e. set data1 value collected from Activity1.

While calling other Activity you'll pass this instance of preview as

```
nextIntent.putExtra("PreviewObject", yourPreviewInstance);
```

And in intent you'll receive using:

```
yourPreview = (Preview)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("PreviewObject");
```

Once you're done collecting data in this Activity, set the value collected to corresponding attribute.May be in this case it will be data2, since we updated data1 earlier. At this point, you have data1 and data2 from 
two Activity.

Now pass this in similar way and you can use it when it reaches the final intent. At final intent, you have all data you need for the Preview filled.

Comment: Hi i have tried this, since i am beginner in java and android I couldn't get the solution to make it work.. But Thanks for your  update. I will learn little bit deeper and will use this solution.